# Accessing info from NSDictionary based on print out

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, nsdictionary

I'm using `NSLog(@"%@", [filter attributes]);` to print out the following from a dictionary:

```
CIAttributeFilterDisplayName = "Color Controls";
CIAttributeFilterName = CIColorControls;
inputBrightness =     {
    CIAttributeClass = NSNumber;
    CIAttributeDefault = 0;
    CIAttributeIdentity = 0;
    CIAttributeSliderMax = 1;
    CIAttributeSliderMin = "-1";
    CIAttributeType = CIAttributeTypeScalar;
};
```

I'm a little confused about `NSDictionarys` and how the information is organized. If I needed to access the attributes for `inputBrightness`, what would be the syntax to retrieve this form the dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to retrieve `inputBrightness` from dictionary `filter`, you can try this:

```
NSDictionary *inputBrightnessDict = filter[@"inputBrightness"]; //or [filter valueForKey:@"inputBrightness"];
```

This will return another dictionary with key value pairs `CIAttributeClass`:`NSNumber`, `CIAttributeDefault`:`0` etc..

You can confirm that `filter[@"inputBrightness"]` is a dictionary by looking at the NSLog statement. Key value pairs enclosed in `{` and `}` represents a dictionary where as `(` and `)` represents an array.

Inorder to retrieve any value from `inputBrightnessDict` you can fetch it as, `inputBrightnessDict[@"CIAttributeType"];`

Answer (score 0):

```
[filter objectForKey:inputBrightness];
```

Hope this helps..

Dictionary work with the concept of object and keys. You can retrieve an object using an key. Key-object come as a pair.